# How to Select Max of a given Column value based on Some other Column Values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a select result like below. and i need to take distinct id and number with maximum of number in the given id

```
id   number
------------
10    150
10    250
10    100
20     13
20     45
20    132
11     16
```

And I need an expected output like this:

```
id   number
-----------
10    250
20    132
11     16
```

I had tried something like

```
select 
    id, max(number) 
from 
    tablename  
where 
    id in (select distinct id from tablename)
```

but I did not get the desired output please help me to solve this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of simple grouping:

```
select id, max(number) as number
from tablename
group by id
```

In this case you get all Ids and maximum for that ID. You can read more about `GROUP BY` [in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)